# Does anyone has experience with software development on a VM in Azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, virtual-machine

Does anyone have experience with developing on a virtual machine in Azure? To clear the matters before someone asks - no, I don't mean deploying and hosting software on a VM in Azure, but literally connecting via RDP to a VM in Azure, where Visual Studio and/or Visual Studio Code, Node.js, tooling etc. are installed and do the coding, debugging, testing etc. there.

If you have tried it then:
1) Did you experience any latency/LAG?
2) Did you have problems installing/configuring third-party software?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of opinions? Yes or no? Good or bad? Try not to ask ambiguous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do. My company has some applications that require me to connect and develop, then test on Azure VMs that host those applications. I have to do the full cycle:

Clone, develop, test, push, publish on the VM each time. I don't have anything amazing to tell you, its pretty much the same thing.

To clarify, both desktop and Web apps

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. You surely also have experience with developing on your developer laptop or PC. When comparing both ways, were you somehow handicapped when developing on the VM in Azure? I mean latency, problems installing or configuring software etc.

Comment: @vassos No, no problems at all. Assuming we are still talking about a windows 10 VM. It's literally the same environment. Only latency problems is with the RDP I was connecting, not the actual machine.

Comment: I have used Azure VM for Visual Studio, Powershell , No problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you for the reply. Exactly the latency implications between typing and seeing what you've typed is what bothers me.

Answer (score 1):

We have many customers who use Azure VMs to host development software. We also have many images that have all the software you need preinstalled

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/using-visual-studio-vm?view=vs-2019

In addition, we offer a variety of VM sizes which can be used specifically for whatever you are developing. As an example, you can use the N-Series VMs if you need GPU software for testing. So depending on your scenario, it can be quite cost effective to use a VM instead of a local machine.

Another advantage of using software that is preinstalled on Azure VMs is that the license comes bundled into the VM cost. So you will have a up front cost model for using the software and the VM.

All in all, it depends on your scenario. However many customers take advantage of Azure VMs to run development environments to help save money and increase the ease of development.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already read the article you linked.